# How to get list of SpannableStrings added in a textview in android(Java)?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am new in android development with Java, I am developing an app in which I have multiple SpannableStrings in a TextView. In this way I can deal each string differently.I have a problem once I have added multiple SpannableStrings in a TextView how can I get a list of those SpannableStrings? I am able to get the click event using ClickSpan, I see no way of getting the list of SpannableStrings added. I need SpannableString to trigger click event programmatically using ClickSpan. Sorry for any non technical terminology. Below is my Code.

Thank You.

```
  for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
        ClickableSpan span = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                //
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                ds.setColor(ds.linkColor);   
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                ds.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
            };


        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(list.get(i));
        spannableString.setSpan(span, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannableStrings.add(spannableString);
        view.append(spannableString);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about to do it like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannableString = (SpannableStringBuilder) textView.getText();
Object[] allSpans = spannableString.getSpans(0, textView.getText().length(), Object.class);
```

Comment: `SpannableString` it's not a span. 

To search for some specific span use the right class like 

`ClickableSpan[] spans = ((SpannableString) textView.getText()).getSpans(0, textView.getText().length(), ClickableSpan.class);`

or in order to find all of them just use `Object`:

`Object[] spans = ((SpannableString) textView.getText()).getSpans(0, textView.getText().length(), Object.class);`

Comment: Always returns empty array

Comment: for me as well return empty array